# Mongoose model deleteOne() only works with hard coded string

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a strange error with mongoose deleteOne() function. Today I wanted to work on my project and got an error while deleting an item from a collection. It simply doesn't delete the document until I use a hardcoded parameter for the options object like this:

```
const { deletedCount } = await Model.deleteOne({symbol: 'hardcoded'})
// results in deletedCount = 1
```

But if I try to use a dynamic string like:

```
const test = 'dynamic'
const { deletedCount } = await Model.deleteOne({symbol: test})
// results in deletedCount = 0
```

It does no longer delete the document from my collection. The strange thing is yesterday it worked fine and deleted the item.

I tried one other thing I read regarding errors with deleteOne():

```
const { deletedCount } = await Model.deleteOne({symbol: JSON.stringifiy(symbol)})
```

But this doesn't work, too.

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I always default to using ids whenever possible to make sure there's no mistake in the data I am targeting with a given operation.
So in this case that would mean using `findByIdAndDelete()` instead.
If I don't know the id of the document I'm trying to delete, then only I'd use `findOneAndDelete()` or `deleteOne()`, as you have, with something other than an id to identify the document I'm looking for.

Are you certain that the key-value pair you're passing to the function exists in your database?

Comment: Yes I have double checked. Adding items to the collection is no problem. But deleting currently doesn't work. I tried findOneAndDelete(), too. Nothing changed. Currently I feel very lost. If I can't remove items dynamicly anymore.

Comment: What if you only use ```findOne()``` to simply fetch the document you're trying to delete? Does it find it correctly? What are the error messages you've been getting with the other operations?

Comment: I found the error. You where on the right track. I accidentally added an additional space at the end of the string. However the error was there long before yesterday. I'm a little bit confused but the error is solved. I will add an answer shortly. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I accidentally added an additional space character at the end of the string. This is very strange because the error was there since the beginning of my project and yesterday it worked.

So for everyone who might have a similar problem:

I have a ejs template file where I render a html element like this:

```
<div id="<%= symbol %> ">
```

Then in my event handler for requesting the server to deleting one item from my list I use the id attribute as a request parameter in the body. In the route handler this parameter is passed to mongoose:

```
const { symbol } = req.body
const { deletedCount } = await Model.deleteOne({ symbol })
```

As I mentioned. In the template file after the last ejs seperator there is an addional space character that caused the error. I spotted this issue by making a copy of the monoogse query and than logged it to the console. There I could see the wrong condition parameter.